# How to get a DateTime object with Pandas when Date and Time are integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

folks. I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

I want to get a DateTime object joining the Date and Time columns. Both are integers. What's the best way of doing so? I am using Pandas.

I am trying to use `to_datetime` but it keeps reverting it back to the initial date in 1970 and interpreting the Date as nanoseconds, I guess. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the 1st row, is the datetime `Jan 4th 1994, 9:30 AM` ?

Comment: Exactly that! It's minute-by-minute data.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, by specifying the format of the date:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Date': [19940104,19940104,19940104],'Time': [930,931,932]})

df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime((df.Date.astype(str)+df.Time.astype(str)), format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

Output:

```
df['DateTime']

0   1994-01-04 09:30:00
1   1994-01-04 09:31:00
2   1994-01-04 09:32:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```